# Taking user input as name of new class instance

Tags: c#, class, oop, object

I am trying to create a class in C# called customer, with 3 variables: name, initial deposit, and monthly deposit amount.

This is for a console program that takes user input for those three variables and keeps asking for more users until the user types nothing and presses enter.

However, the line 
`customer userInputName = new customer(userInputName, userInputInitial, userInputMonthly);` 
is giving me errors. The first userInputName is underlined saying *"a local or parameter named 'userInputName' cannot be delcared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter"*. The second 'userInputName' says *"Argument 1: cannot convert from 'lab4.Program.customer' to 'string' "*.

The only way I can fix this is by changing the first 'userInputName' to something like customer1, but if I do that, I can't continuously make new customers if the user continues typing names.

Ideally, I want to be able to type something like customer.Bob.initialDeposit and have the program able to tell me what Bob's initial Deposit was, etc.

How can I achieve this, or what am I doing wrong?

```
using System;

namespace lab4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("How many months will the customer keep the money in the account?");
            string monthsString = Console.ReadLine();
            int months = Int32.Parse(monthsString);

            bool run = true;
            while (run)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter new customer name: ");

                string userInputName = Console.ReadLine();
                if (userInputName == "")
                {
                    run = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter initial deposit amount: ");
                    string stringInitDeposit = Console.ReadLine();
                    int userInputInitial = Int32.Parse(stringInitDeposit);

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter montly deposit amount: ");
                    string stringMonthDeposit = Console.ReadLine();
                    int userInputMonthly = Int32.Parse(stringMonthDeposit);

                    customer userInputName = new customer(userInputName, userInputInitial, userInputMonthly);
                }

            }
        }


            public class customer
            {
                public string name;
                public int initialDeposit;
                public int monthlyDeposit;

                public customer(string name, int initialDeposit, int monthlyDeposit)
                {
                    this.name = name;
                    this.initialDeposit = initialDeposit;
                    this.monthlyDeposit = monthlyDeposit;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"The only way I can fix this is by changing the first 'userInputName' to something like customer1"_ -- no, not at all. You could also fix this by changing the second one to `customer11`, or anything else other than `userInputName`. But your question is impossible to provide a good answer to, because the third way to fix it would be to just omit the second `userInputName` variable altogether. Your code never does anything with that variable anyway, so it's unclear what it is you actually expected to happen here. Please improve your question so that it's clear what you really need.

Comment: I wrote what I wanted to do with the code. *Ideally, I want to be able to type something like customer.Bob.initialDeposit and have the program able to tell me what Bob's initial Deposit was, etc.* I wanted to have each new customers name to be the name of the variable, but from ps2goat's response below, I understand where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

`string userInputName = Console.ReadLine();`

and

`customer userInputName = new customer(userInputName, userInputInitial, userInputMonthly);`

You are attempting to reuse the same variable name. Pick a new one for the customer (since the name doesn't make sense for that, anyway), and update references to use that new variable name.

If you want to make multiple customers, add the new customer to an array. The variable can still be reused within the while loop.

Example:

```
// add this line outside (above) the while loop: (you will need to import the proper namespace for this: `using System.Collections.Generic;`)
List<Customer> newCustomers = new List<Customer>();


// I renamed this variable. add the line below to put the new customer into the list
customer newCustomer = new customer(userInputName, userInputInitial, userInputMonthly);
newCustomers.Add(newCustomer);

// now you have a list of new customers you can reference outside the while loop.
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it is working exactly how I intended. If I'm understanding correctly, I am adding each new customer, along with all it's properties of name, initial deposit, and monthly deposit to a list, correct?

Comment: That is correct. The next time through the loop, the `newCustomer` variable is recreated, so there is no overwriting of the previous customer data.

Answer (score -1):

To get Bob's deposit you could something like the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

(...)

var customers = new List<Customer>();

//Your logic to create customers here
var c1 = new Customer("Bob", 100, 10);
customers.Add(c1);
var c2 = new Customer("Bob", 200, 20);
customers.Add(c2);
var c3 = new Customer("Alice", 100, 10);
customers.Add(c3);


//Find all Bobs
var bobs = customers.Where(c => c.Name == "Bob");

foreach (var bob in bobs )
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Bob's initial deposit is {bob.InitialDeposit}");
}
```

---

Please note that names of classes are normally capitalised, e.g. `Customer`.

It's also common to keep fields private in classes and use properties for public access.

Here is an variant of the Customer class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer(string name, int initialDeposit, int monthlyDeposit)
    {
        Name = name;
        InitialDeposit = initialDeposit;
        MonthlyDeposit = monthlyDeposit;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public int InitialDeposit { get; }
    public int MonthlyDeposit { get; }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I jumped to answering before reading the full question. Updated now.